# Writing a Set To a File in Python

Tags: python, list, set

I was wondering if there were any pre-made modules in python to remove the opening `Set(` and closing `)` strings from the string:

```
set([`item1`,`item2`,`item3`])
```

so that it would be formatted like a list?

Comment: do you mean as in `s[4:-1]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few different ways to accomplish this. The first two have already been mentioned in answers or comments, but I'd like to add some context as well as a third method.

## 1. Slice the String

As @Pynchia said in his comment, you can simply slice the result. This will work for any set and would be my preferred solution. Very simple:

```
>>> x = set(['item1','item2','item3'])
>>> print str(x)[4:-1]
['item2', 'item3', 'item1']
```

## 2. Convert to a List

As @alecxe said in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35212131/2258915), you could simply convert the variable to a `List` and then convert to a `String`. However, this is mildly hackish because you're creating an entirely new `List` object with whatever overhead that entails just to get its string representation. Probably fine even for pretty large lists, but eventually the overhead will be meaningful.

```
>>> x = set(['item1','item2','item3'])
>>> print list(x)
['item2', 'item3', 'item1']
```

## 3. Create a new class

This might be overkill for your specific situation, but you could create your own `Set` subclass with its own string method. This code is assuming Python 2.

```
class mySet(set):
    def __str__(self):
        return super(Set,self).__str__()[4:-1]
```

And execution example:

```
>>> x = mySet(['item1','item2','item3'])
>>> print x
['item2', 'item3', 'item1']
```

Comment: I think option 1 would be most logical in this situation. Option 3 does seem like overkill because this string conversion only occurs once in my script, so class and function won't be called a second time, and option 2 could lead to heavy processing. Do you agree? Do you think option 1 is the one I should go with in this situation?

Comment: Yes I think 1 definitely makes the most sense. Hope this helped :)

Answer (score 2):

What you see is a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) *string representation*. To get a `list` from a `set`, call `list()` on it:

```
>>> s = set(['item1', 'item2', 'item3'])
>>> s
set(['item2', 'item3', 'item1'])
>>> list(s)
['item2', 'item3', 'item1']
```

Keep in mind that sets are *unordered collections*.